# Serialization of integer and bytebuffer to outputstream in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I have a serialization code that can serialize an object to a bytebuffer. I want to write the length of the buffer first to the stream followed by the bytebuffer itself. Here is how I am writing to the outputStream:

```
MyObject = new MyObject();
//fill in MyObject
...
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("a.txt"));
ByteBuffer buffer = MySerializer.encode(myObject);
int length = buffer.remaining();
out.write(length);
WritableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(out);
channel.write(buffer);
out.close();
```

I verified this code and it seems to be working fine. But when I try to deserialize, I am not able to do it correctly. Here is the snippet of my deserializer code :

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("a.txt"));
int objSize = in.readInt();
byte[] byteArray = new byte[objSize];
...
```

The problem is that the length is not being read properly from stream.
Can anyone help me figure out what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`write` writes a byte. `readInt` reads 4 bytes and combines them to make an `int`.

You probably want to write the length with `writeInt` (which splits the `int` into 4 bytes and writes those).